# I want to group Columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have Data frame which consist different columns and I want to group columns in the bases of AccountID
 [image: in the bases of AccountID]

and expected output looks like this
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? How about starting with the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and go from there?

Comment: I read doc but available method (groupby) in doc is returning me just three columns

Comment: In that case please show your code

Comment: `c=differenc.groupby(['AccountID']).mean()`

Comment: The reason you only get three columns (i'm guessing because I can't see your data) is because only those 3 are numeric, and `.mean()` can't operate on non-numeric columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
uniq_accounts = differenc['AccountID'].unique()
grped = differenc.groupby('AccountID')

## You can get the grouped data for a certain AccountId like this and store in a dictionary:

d = {}
for account in uniq_accounts:
    d[account] = grped.get_group(account)

##Now, dictionary has all accounts data in separate dataframes. You can access like this:

for key in d.keys():
    print(d[key])

## If you want to fetch data for a particular AccountID(lets say 316001718201), you can do:

print(d['316001718201'])
```

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible with the groupby function of a DataFrame, which in this case would probably be `differenc.groupby('AccountID')`

Comment: I already tried this but this only gives three column and ignore remaining columns

Comment: That is very strange, can you show me your code so I can reproduce?

Comment: `c=differenc.groupby(['AccountID']).mean()`

Comment: The three columns you see are; first level group, second level group and the calculated mean. Please see this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html